# Dynamic SQL or WITH Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've been mauling the following over-and-over, trying to maximize code re-usability, and at the same time, keep optimal performance.

I have a SQL query which is very **long and complex**, that I'm trying to run multiple times (6 times to be exact), each time with a different WHERE CLAUSE. It took a lot of effort to get it to the form in which I can interchange the WHERE CLAUSE... but I'm having lots of difficulty running the query for each case.

ie>

```
INSERT INTO table_x (SELECT *
  FROM mst_q (+300 lines query)
 WHERE complex_where_clause_1);

 INSERT INTO table_x (SELECT *
  FROM mst_q (+300 lines query)
 WHERE complex_where_clause_2);
```

I've tried using `UNION ALL`, `WHERE with CASE`, `WHERE with OR`, and thought of even having 6 different `CURSORS` that would independently INSERT the results of each of the 6-cases. **Having 6 different CURSORS works and performance is great, there is way too much duplicate code**, since all that changes is the `WHERE` clause.

I thought, great, [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)! But the "**long and complex**" statement is much larger than the size of a `VARCHAR2`.

Is there a way to do something like the following? This is the bast option I can think of, the only issue is that v_sql will definitely be longer that the size limit of a `VARCHAR2`.

```
v_sql := 'INSERT INTO table_x (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM WHERE ';

v_scen1 := 'complex_where_clause_1';
v_scen2 := 'complex_where_clause_2'

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql || v_scen1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql || v_scen2;
```

Comment: what's wrong with a view?

Comment: The data that gets inserted into "table_x" is not persistent. Meaning, table_x is more of a temp table. If I could run 6 independent CURSORS to populate it once, and be done with it, I would've done that. But the contents of table_x will actually be replaced about 4-times, during a single execution... view wont work for this

Comment: I'm talking about the "(+300 lines query)" bit...

Comment: The where clause is what keeps the (+300 lines query) from producing a Cartesian... not only that, it would probably run 3+hrs..

Comment: ok, I'm going out on a limb here.  If you have nested queries in your 300+ line sql statement, you could replace those with views.  Then reference the views.  That would reduce the amount of code in your 300+ line statement.  Otherwise, if it's that complex a query, you might want to consider breaking it up in plsql and letting plsql do some of the work for you.

Comment: Can you do `WHERE (complex_where_clause_1) OR (complex_where_clause_2)...` in one statement to at least only have one horrific statement to maintain? Perhaps when you bring them together you could even do `WHERE (common_complex_bits) AND ((other_part_1) OR (other_part_2))`.

Comment: do u have a common set of conditions for the six different WHERE clause for example select * from a where col1=col2 and col3=col4 and select * from a where col1=col2 and col4=col5 in this the common condition is col1=col2

Comment: @turboc, I opted to not break up the code to avoid context switches and truly, to keep things together...

Comment: @psaraj12, I tried that already (read my question), and performance tanked.. when you run each condition seperately, the code runs in about 26sec total.. when you use OR, the statement takes 2+HRS... If it were that easy, I would've been done a LONG time ago :)

Comment: @robert my idea is to create a view with the common conditions and then select your data based on that view

Comment: i had similar issue in which case i put the data with common conditions in temp table and get data from temp table it worked out good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... ah, too simple, just use: `v_sql        CLOB;`

I'll elaborate in a few hours; but I was able to do exactly what I was asking if possible... Using `CLOB` breaks down the size limitation of a `VARCHAR2`, and I simply append the `WHERE` clauses and execute sequentially...

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "I thought, great, dynamic SQL! But the "long and complex" statement is much larger than the size of a VARCHAR2."

You could do this if you are still interested in using dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_stmt_part1 || v_sql_stmt_part2 || ....
```

That is to say, just break up your SQL statment into 2 (or more) VARCHAR2 variables and then concatenate them when you do the dynanmic SQL.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's not an acceptable solution for me. I'm not going to be the one maintaining the code, and I'm trying to minimize any confusion. Your approach (works), but leaves room for someone to break the SQL (if they don't realize the statements need to go together) ... thanks for the input though!

Comment: Glad I could help you in some way.  You could comment your code in such a way as to avoid any confusion that may occur with others not realizing the code goes together.  This is what I did and I have had no issues.  Just a thought ... take care.

Comment: Can't you use DBMS_SQL ? Great for very long SQL - even used it to dynamically create stored procs.